# The method 'placemarkFromCoordinates' isn't defined for the type 'Geolocator'. Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am getting the following errors:

Static method 'getPositionStream' can't be accessed through an instance.
Try using the class 'Geolocator' to access the method.dart(instance_access_to_static_member

And

The method 'placemarkFromCoordinates' isn't defined for the type 'Geolocator'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'placemarkFromCoordinates'.dart(undefined_method)

```
  Set<Marker> _markers = {};
  //  this polys will be displayed on the map
  Set<Polyline> _poly = {};
  // this polys temporarely store the polys to destination
  Set<Polyline> _routeToDestinationPolys = {};
  // this polys temporarely store the polys to driver
  Set<Polyline> _routeToDriverpoly = {};

  GoogleMapsServices _googleMapsServices = GoogleMapsServices();
  GoogleMapController _mapController;
  Geoflutterfire geo = Geoflutterfire();
  static LatLng _center;
  LatLng _lastPosition = _center;
  TextEditingController pickupLocationControlelr = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController destinationController = TextEditingController();
  Position position;
  DriverService _driverService = DriverService();
  //  draggable to show
  Show show = Show.DESTINATION_SELECTION;

  //   taxi pin
  BitmapDescriptor carPin;

  //   location pin
  BitmapDescriptor locationPin;

  LatLng get center => _center;

  LatLng get lastPosition => _lastPosition;

  Set<Marker> get markers => _markers;

  Set<Polyline> get poly => _poly;

  GoogleMapController get mapController => _mapController;
  RouteModel routeModel;

  //  Driver request related variables
  bool lookingForDriver = false;
  bool alertsOnUi = false;
  bool driverFound = false;
  bool driverArrived = false;
  RideRequestServices _requestServices = RideRequestServices();
  int timeCounter = 0;
  double percentage = 0;
  Timer periodicTimer;
  String requestedDestination;

  String requestStatus = "";
  double requestedDestinationLat;

  double requestedDestinationLng;
  RideRequestModel rideRequestModel;
  BuildContext mainContext;

//  this variable will listen to the status of the ride request
  StreamSubscription<QuerySnapshot> requestStream;
  // this variable will keep track of the drivers position before and during the ride
  StreamSubscription<QuerySnapshot> driverStream;
//  this stream is for all the driver on the app
  StreamSubscription<List<DriverModel>> allDriversStream;

  DriverModel driverModel;
  LatLng pickupCoordinates;
  LatLng destinationCoordinates;
  double ridePrice = 0;
  String notificationType = "";

  AppStateProvider() {
    _saveDeviceToken();
    fcm.configure(
//      this callback is used when the app runs on the foreground
        onMessage: handleOnMessage,
//        used when the app is closed completely and is launched using the notification
        onLaunch: handleOnLaunch,
//        when its on the background and opened using the notification drawer
        onResume: handleOnResume);

    _setCustomMapPin();
    _getUserLocation();
    _listemToDrivers();
    Geolocator().getPositionStream().listen(_updatePosition);

  }

// ANCHOR: MAPS & LOCATION METHODS
  _updatePosition(Position newPosition){
    position = newPosition;
    notifyListeners();
  }
  Future<Position> _getUserLocation() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    position = await Geolocator().getCurrentPosition();
    List<Placemark> placemark = await Geolocator()
        .placemarkFromCoordinates(position.latitude, position.longitude);

    if (prefs.getString(COUNTRY) == null) {
      String country = placemark[0].isoCountryCode.toLowerCase();
      await prefs.setString(COUNTRY, country);
    }

    _center = LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude);
    notifyListeners();
    return position;
  }

  onCreate(GoogleMapController controller) {
    _mapController = controller;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  setLastPosition(LatLng position) {
    _lastPosition = position;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  onCameraMove(CameraPosition position) {
    //  MOVE the pickup marker only when selecting the pickup location
    if (show == Show.PICKUP_SELECTION) {
      _lastPosition = position.target;
      changePickupLocationAddress(address: "loading...");
      if (_markers.isNotEmpty) {
        _markers.forEach((element) async {
          if (element.markerId.value == PICKUP_MARKER_ID) {
            _markers.remove(element);
            pickupCoordinates = position.target;
            addPickupMarker(position.target);
            List<Placemark> placemark = await Geolocator()
                .placemarkFromCoordinates(
                    position.target.latitude, position.target.longitude);
            pickupLocationControlelr.text = placemark[0].name;
            notifyListeners();
          }
        });
      }
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }
```

PUBSPEC.YAML

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cloud_firestore: any
  cupertino_icons: any
  firebase_auth: any
  firebase_core: any
  firebase_messaging: ^5.0.2
  flutter_google_places: any
  flutter_spinkit: ^4.1.2
  geocoder: any
  geoflutterfire: ^2.0.3+6
  geolocator: any
  get_it: ^1.0.3+2
  google_maps_flutter: any
  google_maps_webservice: any
  http: any
  location: any
  modal_bottom_sheet: ^0.2.2
  percent_indicator: ^2.1.7+2
  provider: ^5.0.0
  rxdart: any
  shared_preferences: any
  url_launcher: any
  uuid: any
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just add the geocoding package as well to your pub.dev as it has been deprecated from Geolocator since geolocator ^6.1.14
Flutter new version Flutter 1.22.5.